# Brush editor in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, brush

I have a class that have a brush property and in my wpf UserControl I have a list of it. When I want change its value its haven’t any editor for change. It think should be exist a method like Category("Appearance") for enable editor for this but I can’t find it :( .

This is my code:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Media;

 namespace Tests
 {
     public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
     {
         List<TestBrush> brushList;
         public List<TestBrush> BrushList
         {
             get{return brushList;}
             set{brushList = value;}
         }
         public UserControl1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
     }


     /// <summary>
     /// Test Brush Class
     /// </summary>
     public class TestBrush
     {
         Brush myBrush=Brushes.Aquamarine;

         [Category("Appearance")]
         public Brush MyBrush
         {
             get{return myBrush;}
             set{myBrush = value;}
         }
     }
 }
```

and when i want change i see this:

[UserControl BrushList Property (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/588vH.png)

and i want something like this:

[BrushEditor (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjUFH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it under "Brush" category:

```
    [Category("Brush")]
    public Brush myBrushProperty { get; set; } = Brushes.Black;
```

It should appear at the top with the color picker widget and other properties that need it.